# python swap function without return statement

Tags: python, return, swap

```
def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
    return list

seq=['abd','dfs','sdfs','fds','fsd','fsd']
print(swapPositions(seq,2,3))
```

Can we do this without the `return` statement?

Comment: Yes; you are modifying `list` in-place. Python convention in such functions is to *not* return the modified object.

Comment: Did you **try it**? When you tried it, **what happened**? Is there an *identifiable problem* with what happened?

Answer (score 1):

`list` object in python is a **mutable object** which means that it gets passed into functions by reference, not by value. So, you are already changing `seq` in-place and there is no need to the `return` statement.

```
def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]


seq=['abd','dfs','sdfs','fds','fsd','fsd']
swapPositions(seq,2,3)
print(seq)
# returns ['abd', 'dfs', 'fds', 'sdfs', 'fsd', 'fsd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python functions usually follow two conventions:

1. Return a *new* object, leaving the argument unchanged.
2. Modify the argument in place, and return `None`.

Your function does the latter, and should omit the `return` statement.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> swapPositions(x, 2, 3)
>>> x
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

If you opt for the former, `x` should be left alone

```
def swapPositions(L, pos1, pos2):
    L = L.copy()
    L[pos1], L[pos2] = L[pos2], L[pos1]
    return L

>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> swapPositions(list, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @mapf That is one of life's great mysteries: I have no idea why :)

Comment: I guess I have to accept that! I thought maybe there was a good reason for that. One small error though, when you define `swapPositions`, you use `pos1` as an argument twice.